# Storing image in Base64 format into String variable gives an error

Tags: java, android, base64

I have a function that convert "bitmap" to "Base64" string

```
public String getBitmapToBase64String(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        if (encoded.trim().length() > 0 && encoded != null) {
            return encoded;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I have a doubt that it gives me an uncompleted image string. So i gave a static value to string variable of image. After that i run the app then i got this error.

```
Error:(652, 21) error: constant string too long
```

Please Help me out
Thanks in advance

Comment: `But I have a doubt that it gives me an uncompleted image string.` No. It does not. Why do you think so? What is it's length?

Comment: `if (encoded.trim().length() > 0 && encoded != null)` If you think that encoded can be null then you should check for that first.

Comment: `So i gave a static value to string variable of image.` It is unclear what you did.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the returned string is very long and won't be stored in the string variable. Instead, use this to reduce the string returned to an object

```
public String getBitmapToBase64String(Bitmap bitmap) {
if (bitmap != null) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    if (encoded.trim().length() > 0 && encoded != null) {

        String CONSTANT = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join( new String[] {encoded} );

        return CONSTANT;

    } else {
        return "";
    }
} else {
    return null;
}
}
```